# Initializing hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-hash

I wanted to have a hash of arrays of counters, with initial values of 0.
Here is my first attempt at the code:

```
my @names = ("", a, b, c);
my %hsh = ();
for $i (1..3)
{
 # I expected this line to give me a fresh new array each time - it did not.
 $hsh{$names[$i]} = (0, 0, 0);  # Assignment line #
 doprint($i); #see below
}
#output is: ARRAY(0x1501128) ARRAY(0x1501128) ARRAY(0x1501128)
```

We see they are all the same array, which is not desired.
To fix the problem, I changed the # Assignment line to this:

```
 $hsh{$names[$i]} = ( );
 push(@{$hash{$names[$i]}}, 0, 0, 0);
 # output is: ARRAY(0x1510c70) ARRAY(0x1510d18) ARRAY(0x1510dc0)
```

Now they are all different arrays, and life is good.

If the Assignment line uses (0, 0, $i) I get different arrays (at least here - they might be reused elsewhere)
but I couldn't fool it by using (0, 0, $i - $i) or a more complex formula to generate a 0 value.

Is this some sort of optimization by Perl?  Why isn't (0, 0, 0) a new array each time? Would (0, 0) or (0, 0, 0, 0) be different?

For the sake of completeness, here is the print subroutine:

```
sub doprint
{
 my $i = shift;
 print (\@{$hsh{$names[$i]}}, " ");
}
```

---- The following edit is on the morning of Feb 9 after the "there is no array comment" - I wanted to add some code and comments don't allow that very well.

OK: $h{$i} = (0, 0, 0); initializes it to a scalar value of 0.
But, as indicated in the output below, there's an array somewhere.
Did writing $h{$i}[$i] create @-something alongside the scalars?

```
my %h = ();
sub dotest
{
 my $desc = shift;
 print "    # $desc\n";
 for (0, 1, 2)
 {
  $h{$_}[$_] += 1 + $_;
 }

 for (0, 1, 2)
 {
  print "    # $_: $h{$_} ";
  print "# @{$h{$_}}" . " # $h{$_}[$_] \n";
 }
 print "\n";
}

%h = ( );
$h{0} = [0, 0, 0];
$h{1} = [0, 0, 0];
$h{2} = [0, 0, 0];
dotest("Initialize to [0, 0, 0]");

%h = ( );
$h{0} = (0, 0, 0);
$h{1} = (0, 0, 0);
$h{2} = (0, 0, 0);
dotest("Initialize to (0,0,0)");

%h = ( );
dotest("No initialization");

%h = ( );
$h{0} = \@{(0, 0, 0)};
$h{1} = \@{(0, 0, 0)};
$h{2} = \@{(0, 0, 0)};
dotest("Initialize to \\\@{(0, 0, 0)}");


# Initialize to [0, 0, 0] - Separate arrays, initialized to zeros.
# 0: ARRAY(0x10ca5e0) # 1 0 0 # 1 
# 1: ARRAY(0x10ca778) # 0 2 0 # 2 
# 2: ARRAY(0x2709da0) # 0 0 3 # 3 

# Initialize to (0,0,0) - scalars AND a shared array?
# 0: 0 # 1 2 3 # 1 
# 1: 0 # 1 2 3 # 2 
# 2: 0 # 1 2 3 # 3 

# No initialization  - separate arrays, initialized to null
# 0: ARRAY(0x2709e48) # 1 # 1 
# 1: ARRAY(0x10ca718) #  2 # 2 
# 2: ARRAY(0x2709da0) #   3 # 3 

# Initialize to \@{(0, 0, 0)} - reusing the shared array from previous?
# 0: ARRAY(0x2709d88) # 2 4 6 # 2 
# 1: ARRAY(0x2709d88) # 2 4 6 # 4 
# 2: ARRAY(0x2709d88) # 2 4 6 # 6
```

Answer (score 3):

[Dave Cross has already showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66074866/2766176) how to do what you wanted to accomplish. But, here are the gory details.

An assignment to a scalar is in scalar context, and a single-element access to a hash is a scalar. So, this is in scalar context:

```
$hash{key} = ( 0, 0, 0 );
```

The operator on the right hand side of the assignment is the comma. In scalar context, the [comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Comma-Operator) evaluates its left hand side then discards the results. It evaluates the right hand side and returns that. See [perlfaq4](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?) where I also explain this. It's a feature from C and shows up in several other languages.

It's easier to see when the values aren't special:

```
$hash{key} = ( 9, 56, 137 );
```

So, start evaluating the right side in scalar context:

```
$hash{key} = (   9, 56,   137 );
$hash{key} = ( ( 9, 56 ), 137 );

$hash{key} = ( 56, 137 );

$hash{key} = ( 137 );
```

You end up with the result of the rightmost evaluation. That's the same as:

```
$hash{key} = 137;
```

Some people (ab)use this to combine two statements that would otherwise have to be on separate lines (not in Perl, really, but others, [maybe JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)):

```
my $foo = (  ($sideeffect=$a), ($b = $c) );
```

Or, you can combine expressions in places where you normally only use one (although the who thing is an expression):

```
for( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $j++, $i++ ) { ... }
```

Now, there's the second part of the problem. You have a non-reference value for that key, then you try to dereference it to use the array in `push`. That doesn't work because it was never a reference.

Comment: I initialize $hash{$key} in various ways, then do $hash{$key}[$i]++ to count.  Using [list of values] or push(list of values), I get a properly initialized list of values for each key.  If I do nothing, or $hash{$key} = (), each key gets its own array, uninitialized.  So I'm left with this question: why does $hash{$key} = (0, 0, 0) result in all the keys seeming to share the Same Array?  ( $hash{"a"}[1]++; $hash{"b"}[1]++; will then print 2 for subscript 1 of both $hash{"a"} and $hash{"b"}. )

Comment: There's no array, as I explained and as Dave Cross showed. They aren't sharing anything.

Comment: Please see large edit to original question. thanks

Comment: There's no array in what you were originally doing. Read my answer. Do what Dave Cross told you to do. Move on in life. The rest of the stuff you changed to has no bearing on the original question and it's poor form to change the question out from under us after you already have an answer. If you have a new question, ask a new question. The rest just confuses anyone else reading this later.

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't do what you think:

```
$hsh{$names[$i]} = (0, 0, 0);
```

`(0, 0, 0)` is not an array, it's a list. And you can't store an array (or, indeed, a list) in a hash element. You can only store scalar values in a hash.

You can get round this by storing a *reference* to an array in your hash. And the easiest way to do that is to use the anonymous array constructor (`[ ... ]`).

```
$hsh{$names[$i]} = [0, 0, 0];
```

Comment: Thank you ... changing (0, 0, 0) to [0, 0, 0] solves the problem, but I'm still a little confused.   Can you explain what got stored in the hash when I set the value to (0,0,0), vs (0,0,1) and ( ) and then pushed a list onto that?

Comment: @TG: That's what [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) is for :-)

Comment: Well, it's really even worse. It's not even a list. It's the comma operator in scalar context. It evaluates its left hand side and discards the result, then evaluates the right hand side and returns it. It's easier to see when the items are unusual, like ( 4, 9, 137 ). People often think you get the number of elements because they test with  (1, 2, 3), and 3 just happens to be the number of elements as well as the last item.